# Postfix Notation in R language

Tags: r, postfix-notation

I need to represent a non linear function as an expression by Postfix Notation in R language, but I do not know how to do it? is any body can help me.

Comment: Produce a reproducible example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @ Aaghaz Hussain . thank you for your answer. I can not understand completely. Is it possible to add some example , for example a simple instance like log(1+2*x1/(1+3*x2)). thanks in advance